# MS Access 2016 VBA causes "Enter parameter value" window

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with filter textbox. Filter works as a macro command "ApplyFilter" with following filter string:

```
[fullname] & [phoneNumber] Like '*' & [Forms]![frmTest]![frmFilter] & '*'
```

It works until I try to add VBA code to the form. Even if there is no code in VBA module I get "Enter parameter Value: [Forms]![frmTest]![frmFilter]" popup window when I try to apply filter.

If I set "HasModule" property of the form to "No" the filter works again.

It's not only just about filter or macro commands. It's the same with referencing form values in SQL queries like [Forms]![frmTest]![frmFilter]. It works without VBA module. It doesn't work if form has VBA module - "Enter parameter value" window appears.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's an issue with non-latin characters in form controls names. Such controls are displayed as "?????" in VBA module. I made a new form and renamed all controls with latin characters and everything works with enabled VBA module. As soon as I add a button with non-latin name everything breaks and starts working after deleting it.